# How to export MobaXTerm Tunnels?

Tags: mobaxterm

I want to export MobaXterm tunnels to another computer. Is there any way?
I've tried exporting sessions, but tunnels are not included.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

There is a MobaXterm.ini in the Mobaxterm dir.
Last entry block of that is
[PortForawrding]

everything beneath are the settings of the tunnels.
Just copi that part into the ini-file and you are done (just enter it including the [PortForwarding] if the entry doesen't exist in the new fike).

Answer (score 0):

You can export the full configuration of the MobaXterm go to tool bar click on configuration and export all configuration . you must know the master password you set for MobaXterm and export all configuration in you desire location. While importing again click on configuration and import all configuration with master password . Everything will be exported with sessions and tunnels .